# java.lang.NullPointerException when calling getters

Tags: java, constructor, nullpointerexception, getter-setter

This's an exercise from my Java course, I need to print out "Rouge" on the screen but something goes wrong and I can't figure out what it is. Help me, please!
Here is my code:

```
public class Cercle {
    public Couleur couleur;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cercle cercle = new Cercle();
        cercle.couleur.setDescription("Rouge");
        System.out.println(cercle.couleur.getDescription());
    }

    public void Cercle() {
        this.couleur = new Couleur();

    }

    public class Couleur {
        String description;

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey! Is `public void Cercle() {` supposed to be a class? Or is it supposed to be a constructor?

Comment: Yah, I saw the problem, thanks akuzminykh

Comment: Then I have bad news for you: Constructors don't have a return type. So it shall be `public Cercle() {`.

Comment: cercle.couleur.setDescription("Rouge"); -- here couleur seems to be inner class? It is not instantiated-- also always best to show the exception stacktrace